# How to validate different input submit buttons in one form using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make the below code only display the "Are you sure you want to proceed deleting the selected?" javascript message only when I click on the delete input button my my form. Can someone please help me? The other input buttons I just want to display "You do not have any selected files."

My checkbox[] is an array and those values are being generated through mysql/php.

```
  <script type = "text/javascript">
  function confirm_update() {
  var chkCount = 0;
  var arrCheckboxes = document.formtop.elements["checkbox[]"];
  for (var i=0; i<arrCheckboxes.length; i++) {
    if(arrCheckboxes[i].checked == true) {
        chkCount++;
    }
  }
    if (chkCount === 0) {
    alert("You do not have any selected files.");
    return false;
   } else {
      return confirm("Are you sure you want to proceed deleting the selected?");
  }
 }

 </script>






  <form   name="formtop"  onsubmit="return confirm_update();"  method="POST" action=""    >

<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" id="Text_Buttons" >
 <tr>
<td align="center"><input id="content-button" style="width:90px;" type="Button"    name="Preferences_button" value="Edit Ad" ></td>     
<td align="center"><input id="content-button" style="width:90px;" type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete Ad" ></td>
 <td align="center"><input id="content-button" style="width:90px;" type="submit" name="pause" value="Pause" ></td>
<td align="center"><input id="content-button" style="width:90px;" type="submit" name="resume" value="Resume" ></td>
 </tr>
 </table>



 <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="1" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the buttons from `type="submit"` to `type="button"` and then add an event listener for 'click' on them where you display the message and then submit the form.